# Bootstrap Modal. include image dynamically with Jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to open a `Modal` that shows the image the user clicks on. So, I have many images with the class `.image`

```
<a href="#">
    <img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_image" src="..." class="image thumbnail img-responsive">
</a>
```

I have a `modal`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_image" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal_imagen" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <img class = "image_modal" src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also following `JQuery` code that is supposed to define the modal's image:

```
$('.image').click(function(){
    var new_src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#image_modal').attr('src', new_src);
});
```

But it is not working. Hope it is not a dumb error, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try something like this ([Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qyvL7ppc/)):

```
$('#modal_image').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   var src = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('src');
   $(this).find('.modal-body > img.image_modal').attr('src', src);
});
```

Check more on [Bootstrap Website](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

> About **show.bs.modal** event:
>
> This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
>   If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the
>   **relatedTarget** property of the event.